# Dynamic creation of JSON objects

Tags: json, go

Below is a working code for extracting custom struct types from a JSON . It uses UnmarshalJSON() to create an array of the objects . Can this be further simplified , as the list of vehicles in the JSON file would increase and is there a way to not use the switch statement to create the objects.

JSON File Data:
{
"vehicle":
[
"car",
"truck"
]
}

Code:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "os"
    "reflect"
)

type driveAPI interface {
    drive()
}

type car struct{}

func (car) drive() {
    fmt.Println("Driving a car")
}

type truck struct{}

func (truck) drive() {
    fmt.Println("Driving a truck")
}

type vehicle struct {
    Value []driveAPI
}

func (v *vehicle) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
    var typ struct {
        Type []string `json:"vehicle"`
    }

    if err := json.Unmarshal(data, &typ); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    fmt.Println("Vehicle Type", typ.Type)
    for _, t := range typ.Type {
        switch t {
        case "car":
            fmt.Println("car new")
            v.Value = append(v.Value, new(car))
        case "truck":
            fmt.Println("truck new")
            v.Value = append(v.Value, new(truck))
        }

    }

    return nil
}

func main() {

    jsnFile, err := os.Open("users.json")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Println("Succefully Opened file")

    defer jsnFile.Close()

    byteValue, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(jsnFile)

    vh := new(vehicle)
    if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(byteValue), &vh); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(vh.Value))
    for _, r := range vh.Value {
        r.drive()
    }

}
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because its solution is just a normal language construct unrelated to the question and its code.

Answer (score 3):

Use a type registry:

```
var registeredTypes=map[string]func() driveAPI{}

func init() {
  registeredTypes["car"]=func() driveAPI {return &car{}}
  registeredTypes["truck"]=func() driverAPI {return &truck{}}
}
...

for _, t := range typ.Type {
   if f, ok:=registeredTypes[t]; ok {
      v.Value = append(v.Value, f())
   }
}
```

Comment: This would mean maintaining a global registry of the different vehicle types, trying to avoid keeping anything global

Comment: This is how it is done in stdlib as well. You can use package level map with a `Register` exported function.

Comment: @AiD well, it's not global, it's local to your package. It could even be local to the unmarshal function (at some cost to flexibility). But it needs to exist.